# How to explode this string into an array like this?

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I'm trying to break up this string,

```
AFRIKAANS = af
ALBANIAN = sq
AMHARIC = am
ARABIC = ar
ARMENIAN = hy
AZERBAIJANI = az
BASQUE = eu
BELARUSIAN = be
BENGALI = bn
BIHARI = bh
BULGARIAN = bg
BURMESE = my
CATALAN = ca
CHEROKEE = chr
CHINESE = zh
```

Into an array like this

```
$lang_codes['chinese'] = "zh";
```

So the name of the language is the key, and the value is the language code. This is really simple, but I just can't get my head around it. I've taken a brake from programming, too long, obviously...

I've tried exploding at `\n` then using a `foreach`, exploding again at `=` but I can't seem to piece it together the way I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've tried exploding at \n then using a foreach, exploding again at " = "

I think this is exactly the right approach.

```
$lines = explode("\n", $langs);
$lang_codes = array();

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    list ($lang, $code) = explode(" = ", $line, 2);
    $lang_codes[$lang] = $code;
}
```

---

If you want the language to be in lowercase, as in your example (`$lang_codes['chinese']`), you'll need to call `strtolower`:

```
$lang_codes[strtolower($lang)] = $code;
```

---

See the PHP manual for more on these functions:

- [`list`](http://php.net/list)
- [`explode`](http://php.net/explode)

Answer (score 2):

Although the explode answers are technically correct, I immediately thought that you were trying to parse an INI file. Here's the simpler approach that does exactly what you want.

```
<?php
$string = "AFRIKAANS = af
ALBANIAN = sq
AMHARIC = am
ARABIC = ar
ARMENIAN = hy
AZERBAIJANI = az
BASQUE = eu
BELARUSIAN = be
BENGALI = bn
BIHARI = bh
BULGARIAN = bg
BURMESE = my
CATALAN = ca
CHEROKEE = chr
CHINESE = zh";

$array = array_change_key_case( parse_ini_string( $string ) );

echo $array['chinese'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Mayb you shold do:

```
$array = explode("\n" , $string);
$finalArray =array();
$foreach ($array as $value){
      $array2 = explode( ' = ', $value);
      $finalArray[$array2[1]] =  $array2[0];

}
```

Comment: That won't work, because `\n` is not interpreted as a line break inside single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$str ="AFRIKAANS = af
ALBANIAN = sq
AMHARIC = am
ARABIC = ar
ARMENIAN = hy
AZERBAIJANI = az
BASQUE = eu
BELARUSIAN = be
BENGALI = bn
BIHARI = bh
BULGARIAN = bg
BURMESE = my
CATALAN = ca
CHEROKEE = chr
CHINESE = zh";

$arr  = explode("\n", $str);
$lang_mapped = array();

foreach ($arr as $line) {
    list ($lang, $code) = explode(" = ", $line, 2);
    $lang_mapped[$lang] = $code;
}
$arr = explode("\n", $str); 
echo "<pre>";
print_r($lang_mapped);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```