# Explode string then create array

Tags: php, arrays

I am having difficulties in exploding string by "-" and creating a new array.

I get values in an array over checkbox from the HTML table. 
Values are in the string which needs to be separated by "-" and form new array under array (array example below).

At the end I should get array[0]

```
[0]=>002251/18
[1]=>1
[2]=>1000
[3]=>5500.00
[4]=>800
```

I need final output:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

  $paketi = array(); 
  $prikolica = $_POST["truck"];         
  $nalozi[] = $_POST["items"];

}
```

nalozi[] -> OUTPUT

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(28) "002251/18-1-1000-5500.00-800"
    [1]=>
    string(28) "002251/18-2-1000-5500.00-800"
    [2]=>
    string(28) "002251/18-3-1000-5500.00-800"
  }
}
```

Comment: Straight away the issue I see is `$_POST["items"];` is an array and you're not looping it (or setting it correctly) to construct your secondary array, you're just dumping the whole contents into the first key

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to explode this string into an array like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594878/how-to-explode-this-string-into-an-array-like-this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You need to iterate over `$_POST["items"]` first

2.Explode this array each individual value by `-` and assign this new coming array to your `$nalozi` array.

```
foreach($_POST["items"][0] as $items){
 $nalozi[] = explode('-',$items);
}
print_r($nalozi);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/998660